# en POST / error 500 TypeError: values.map is not a function

Tags: function, map, router, http-post, error500

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]A que se debe este error?
Al decir values.map se refiere al uso de .map específicamente o a un método cualquiera que itera y que está funcionando mal???
Porque no puedo encontrar donde está el error.

Estoy trabajando con react, redux, sequalize, express. Cuando testeo el POST usando Postman desde el back funciona muy bien, pero cuando lo enlaso con el front desde el componente que debe usar el POST me devuelve ese error ¿???

Comment: Hola, Mauricio! Te recomiendo leer [ask]: Sin código que revisar es casi imposible ayudarte. Lo único que sacamos en claro es que tienes una variable llamada `values` que no tiene una función `map`

Comment: gracias Pablo Lozano, ahí comparto img de pantalla

Comment: Cuando uso el POST desde postman si se carga la tabla de mi base de datos, pero cuando lo solicito desde el front me devuelve este error. En el archivo db (mi base de datos) el require que uso para importar mi tabla (donde quiero cargar datos) desde la carpeta models, bueno ese require aparece con tres puntitos por debajo del inicio de la palabra, a que se debe eso? ahí comparto img tb